# Pyqt suggestions not available when loading ui file

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, desktop-application, qt-designer

**I'm using Qt Designer** to design GUI, but when I load `Ui` file in my code.

**Problem1**

I'm unable to get code suggestions like what attributes I have in my GUI etc.

**Solution to above**

Instead of loading `Ui` file, I convert it in `.py` with `pyuic5 -o register_ui.py Register.ui`, with this I get:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Register.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_RegisterationWin(object):
    def setupUi(self, RegisterationWin):
        RegisterationWin.setObjectName("RegisterationWin")
        RegisterationWin.resize(414, 698)
        RegisterationWin.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(414, 698))
        RegisterationWin.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(746, 806))
        RegisterationWin.setWindowOpacity(0.97)
        RegisterationWin.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(RegisterationWin)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.top_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.top_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.top_frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.top_frame.setObjectName("top_frame")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.top_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.welcome_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.top_frame)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.welcome_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.welcome_lbl.setObjectName("welcome_lbl")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.welcome_lbl, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.top_frame)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(19)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_6, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.register_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.top_frame)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.register_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.register_lbl.setObjectName("register_lbl")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.register_lbl, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.top_frame)
        self.mid_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.mid_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.mid_frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.mid_frame.setObjectName("mid_frame")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.mid_frame)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.mid_frame)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.fn_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.fn_lbl.setObjectName("fn_lbl")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.fn_lbl, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.lb_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.lb_lbl.setObjectName("lb_lbl")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.lb_lbl, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.dob_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.dob_lbl.setObjectName("dob_lbl")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.dob_lbl, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.gender_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.gender_lbl.setObjectName("gender_lbl")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.gender_lbl, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.email_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.email_lbl.setObjectName("email_lbl")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.email_lbl, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.pass_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.pass_lbl.setObjectName("pass_lbl")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pass_lbl, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.confirm_pass_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.confirm_pass_lbl.setObjectName("confirm_pass_lbl")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.confirm_pass_lbl, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.frame_5 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.mid_frame)
        self.frame_5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_5.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_5.setObjectName("frame_5")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_5)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.fn_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame_5)
        self.fn_input.setObjectName("fn_input")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.fn_input)
        self.ln_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame_5)
        self.ln_input.setObjectName("ln_input")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.ln_input)
        self.dob_input = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.frame_5)
        self.dob_input.setMaximumDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(3000, 12, 31), QtCore.QTime(23, 59, 59)))
        self.dob_input.setMinimumDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(1900, 1, 1), QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)))
        self.dob_input.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.dob_input.setObjectName("dob_input")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.dob_input)
        self.gender_input = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.frame_5)
        self.gender_input.setObjectName("gender_input")
        self.gender_input.addItem("")
        self.gender_input.addItem("")
        self.gender_input.addItem("")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.gender_input)
        self.email_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame_5)
        self.email_input.setObjectName("email_input")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.email_input)
        self.pass_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame_5)
        self.pass_input.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.pass_input.setObjectName("pass_input")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pass_input)
        self.confirm_pass_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame_5)
        self.confirm_pass_input.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.confirm_pass_input.setObjectName("confirm_pass_input")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.confirm_pass_input)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_5)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.mid_frame)
        self.submit_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.submit_frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.submit_frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.submit_frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 50))
        self.submit_frame.setToolTip("")
        self.submit_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.submit_frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.submit_frame.setObjectName("submit_frame")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.submit_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.submit_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.submit_frame)
        self.submit_button.setObjectName("submit_button")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.submit_button, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.submit_frame)
        self.bottom_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.bottom_frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.bottom_frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.bottom_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.bottom_frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.bottom_frame.setObjectName("bottom_frame")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.bottom_frame)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.account_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.bottom_frame)
        self.account_lbl.setObjectName("account_lbl")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.account_lbl, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.signin_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.bottom_frame)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.signin_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.signin_lbl.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.signin_lbl.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(52, 101, 164);")
        self.signin_lbl.setObjectName("signin_lbl")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.signin_lbl, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.bottom_frame)
        RegisterationWin.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(RegisterationWin)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(RegisterationWin)

    def retranslateUi(self, RegisterationWin):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        RegisterationWin.setWindowTitle(_translate("RegisterationWin", "Registeration FORM"))
        self.welcome_lbl.setText(_translate("RegisterationWin", "Welcome To"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("RegisterationWin", "Task Management System"))
        self.register_lbl.setText(_translate("RegisterationWin", "Registeration Form"))
        self.fn_lbl.setText(_translate("RegisterationWin", "First Name"))
        self.lb_lbl.setText(_translate("RegisterationWin", "Last Name"))
        self.dob_lbl.setText(_translate("RegisterationWin", "DOB"))
        self.gender_lbl.setText(_translate("RegisterationWin", "Gender"))
        self.email_lbl.setText(_translate("RegisterationWin", "E-mail"))
        self.pass_lbl.setText(_translate("RegisterationWin", "Password"))
        self.confirm_pass_lbl.setText(_translate("RegisterationWin", "Confirm Password"))
        self.dob_input.setDisplayFormat(_translate("RegisterationWin", "dd/MM/yyyy"))
        self.gender_input.setItemText(0, _translate("RegisterationWin", "Other"))
        self.gender_input.setItemText(1, _translate("RegisterationWin", "Male"))
        self.gender_input.setItemText(2, _translate("RegisterationWin", "Female"))
        self.submit_button.setText(_translate("RegisterationWin", "Submit"))
        self.account_lbl.setText(_translate("RegisterationWin", "Already Have an Account? "))
        self.signin_lbl.setText(_translate("RegisterationWin", "SignIn"))
```

And inherit this class so that I don't lost my work every time I change the design and regenerate this file.

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlQuery
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

from register_ui import Ui_RegisterationWin
import psycopg2


class RegisterationWinSignals(Ui_RegisterationWin):
    def __init__(self, win):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(win)
        self.retranslateUi(win)
        self.submit_button.clicked.connect(self.submit_handle)

        try:
            self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
                host='localhost',
                dbname='chat_db',
                user='postgres',
                password='12345678qQ',
                port=5432
            )
            self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
            print('connect')

            create_query = """
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
            First_Name  varchar(70),
            Last_Name  varchar(70),
            dob date,
            gender varchar(1),
            email varchar(80) PRIMARY KEY,
            password varchar(40) NOT NULL
            )
            """
            self.cur.execute(create_query)
            self.conn.commit()
            # self.conn.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"not connect\n{e}")

    def submit_handle(self):

        fn = self.fn_input.text()
        ln = self.ln_input.text()
        dob = self.dob_input.text()
        email = self.email_input.text()
        gender = self.gender_input.currentText()
        password = self.pass_input.text()
        confirm_password = self.confirm_pass_input.text()

        print(f'{fn} {ln}')
        print(f'{dob}')
        print(f'{email}')
        print(f'{gender}')
        print(f'{password}')
        print(f'{confirm_password}')
        if gender == 'Male':
            gender = 'M'
        elif gender == 'Female:':
            gender = 'F'
        else:
            gender = 'O'

        try:
            query = f"INSERT INTO users (First_Name, Last_Name, dob, gender, email, password) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s); "
            values = (fn, ln, dob, gender, email, password)
            self.cur.execute(query, values)
            self.conn.commit()
        except psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation:
            print('already exist')
            self.email_input.setStyleSheet("""
            border : 1px solid ;
            border-color : red;
            background-color: rgba(204, 0, 0, 0.2);
            """)
            self.submit_button.setEnabled(False)
```

**It solved my previous problem but** It results in:

**Problem2**

Now signals and handlers unable to work in inherited class when I assign them. Everything else is working fine, I'm getting suggestions, attributes, can change attributes etc.

**Now I'm looking for solution that solve my problem1 or problem2**

Comment: Change to `class RegisterationWinSignals(QMainWindow, Ui_RegisterationWin)` and use `self` instead of `win` (which isn't needed at all).

Comment: I try this but still not working.

Comment: Works fine for me. What exactly do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Can You Share your code?

Comment: I mean *your* code works fine for me. What is the problem? What is "not working"?